# Under what sufficient conditions $f$ is non-constant function?

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f$ is an entire function. Then under which of these conditions, $f$ is not a constant function:
>
> (1) ${\bf Im}\,f(z)>0$ on complex plane.
>
> (2) $f(n)=3,$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}.$
>
> (3) $f'(0)=0$ and $|f'(z)|\leq 3, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: What are your thoughts, where are you stuck?

Comment: Any thoughts on any of those?

Comment: i am trying by using cauchy riemann equation, but couldnt proceed